# Asciiquarium, xscreensaver and xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, xscreensaver

I downloaded Asciiquarium perl script from this site:

http://www.robobunny.com/projects/asciiquarium/html/

I copied it to "local binary" and it's run properly if execute as program.

what I wonder, how do I start it as a xscreensaver?

tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: you currently can't.

You can't use any program as screensaver but you need program written directly for use as xscreensaver module. You can see documentation on http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~liberato/screensaver/

Currently there are only Mac OS X, KDE and Windows variants of asciiquarium screensaver but none has been probably written for xscreensaver.

Of course, you have option to switch from xscreensaver to KDE screensaver if you don't mind installing many required libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You could run it in a screensaver that could execute external commands. For instance, the apple2 screensaver that comes with xscreensaver-data-extra lets you do this. To see what it would look like try this:

```
/usr/lib/xscreensaver/apple2 -program ./asciiquarium -fast -mode text
```

It looks like other people have made screensaver versions of asciiquarium so you might check those out as well.